# changing defined height to content relative

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a div with a defined height when the window is 'screen' size. It has a div inside with content that is centred vert and horiz. When in mobile/tablet size I want to remove the defined height and I want the div to be as big as the content inside it (the height value only).

HTML - Bootstrap & Wordpress framework

```
<article>
 <div class="article-L" style="...">

  <div class="Lg-cell-wrap">
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
  </div>            

 </div><!-- / bg-img-L -->  
</article>
```

CSS

```
article {
 position: relative;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0;
}

.article-L { height: 570px; }

.Lg-cell-wrap {
 position: relative;
 width: 85%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

I tried adding

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {

  .article-L { height: auto; }
}
```

but it doesn't work

EDIT

https://jsfiddle.net/4voLqj5a/6/

for some reason I can only get the result from creating a fiddle. I want a set height in screen size, relative height in smaller screens

Comment: please share the jsfiddle and with little bit more info that what you want to achieve..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4voLqj5a/6/

for some reason I can only get the opposite result from creating a fiddle. I want a set height in screen size, relative height in smaller screens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default behavior of `height: auto;`:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/height/

> (height) will be as tall as the content inside it is, or zero if there is no content

This is what I see when running your code, and it behaves as expected. Are you not seeing this or what were you expecting? The `transform` set at `-50%` is what is pulling the inner div off the screen. Override that in the media query also if you don't want that.

```css
article {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}
.article-L {
  height: 570px;
  background: yellow;
}
.Lg-cell-wrap {
  background: pink;
  position: relative;
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .article-L {
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="article-L">

    <div class="Lg-cell-wrap">
      <h1>The Content Title</h1>
      <!-- the content -->
      <p>Gumbo beet greens corn soko endive gumbo gourd. Parsley shallot courgette tatsoi pea sprouts fava bean collard greens dandelion okra wakame tomato. Dandelion cucumber earthnut pea peanut soko zucchini.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- / bg-img-L -->
</article>
```

Comment: The code centers the 'Lg-cell-wrap' inside a 'article-L' with a specific height when it's screen size. But I can't get it to go back to being the size of the content in smaller screens

Comment: I managed to solve it, I have to give you credit since looking through your code solved it. (I have to remove overflow:hidden, translate, and position)